# From Any Camel Route

Tags: apache-camel

I'm new to apache Camel, attempting to write a basic test.  However, I was curious as to whether there was a way to write a route that would accept any "from".  For instance, I tried something like:

```
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("*").to("mock:result");
         }
    };
}
```

But I think it didn't work.  Is this even allowed in Camel?  If so, how would I do it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't wildcard a 'from'. Was this just curiosity or are you trying to use it?

Comment: more curiosity.  Everything I was reading showed a specific "from" on a route, wasn't sure if there were reasons why this would always be necessary, or if there was a special keyword/queue that could go to any destination.

Comment: What do you mean by any? Camel have a dozens of connectors, you mean it can read any of them (JMS queue, file from FTP, file from filesystem, http request (cxf), etc... ) . Normally you have to know from where (and which protocol) you are going to read first.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is not possible.

Camel has extensive support for unit testing. Check the online docs at, and check out the advice with etc.

- http://camel.apache.org/testing
- http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html

And there is also an interceptor you can use

- http://camel.apache.org/intercept

Comment: As an extra comment on the Camel Testing Support; It's currently quite hard to test multiple routes within the testing framework. For instance if you load 2 different camel files and want to modify a specific camel context

Comment: Yeah, I'm using this in the camel testing stuff - if you look at the first link my method is almost verbatim from the quick-start example (which I got running first before altering).  I was more curious with regard to a route being able to accept any "from".  Do you know anything more about why this is not possible/alternative techniques to accomplish this?